# Fibre product of smooth schemes over a singular scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $k$ be a (perfect) field, let $f:X\to Z$ and $g:Y\to Z$ be morphisms of varieties (reduced separated scheme of finite type) over $k$, where $X$ and $Y$ are smooth over $k$, **whereas $Z$ is not**. Can we always show that the fibre product $X\times_Z Y$ is smooth over $k$? If so, does that rely on $Z$ being reduced, or can it be proven more generally? A reference would be appreciated.

Comment: Of course not. This is not true even if $Z$ is smooth. Take, for instance $X$ and $Y$ to be smooth hypersurfaces in $Z$ whose intersection is singular (because of tangency).

Comment: @Sasha: Yes, thank you! Would that change if $X\times_Z Y$ is already known to be reduced?

Comment: No, for instance an intersection of two smooth hypersurfaces may be reduced but singular.